# flex array to string from loop

Tags: arrays, string, apache-flex, loops

I am able to trace the result without any problem. however i would like to convert the result into a string and not an Array. the reason i want to do this is because i need to do a search and replace on each string that is returned.Also can someone help to put each line of the array in a string so i can do the search and replace.Sorry guys i am a newbie in flex dev. thank you very much for your help

```
 var myArrayOfLines:Array = ul.data.split(/\n/);
 var line:String;
 for each (var lineRaw:String in myArrayOfLines)
 { 
  //line:String = lineRaw.match(pattern);
 trace(lineRaw.match(pattern));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your array stores strings.You can define `String` variable(for example `str`) and the iterate the array and append each item of the array to str like this:

```
var str : String = "";
for each (var line : String in myArrayOfLines) {
    str += line;
}
//you can do some match and replace operation on the str variable, 
//since it contains all the elements of the arr.
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to replace something in each line, and just join the result, you don't need to split it in lines. You can just use the replaceAll method.

```
replaceAll("pattern to search","string to put where pattern match");
```

If you still need to replace and join all the lines, you can do something like this

```
    var myArrayOfLines:Array = ul.data.split(/\n/);
    var line:String;
    var result:String = "";
    for each (var lineRaw:String in myArrayOfLines){ 
        // you can use replace or replaceAll
        line:String = lineRaw.replace(pattern, "whatever you want to put in places");
        result += line;
        result += "\n"; // use this line if you want to add the break lines again
    }
```

If you want to still use the match(), it returns all the matches and not a single string:

```
var str:String = "bob@example.com, omar@example.org"; 
var pattern:RegExp = /\w*@\w*\.[org|com]+/g; 
var results:Array = str.match(pattern);
// the result is ["bob@example.com","omar@example.org"]
```

So, if you have something like this, you can do a for to iterate all the matches.

```
    var lines:Array = lineRaw.match(pattern);
    for each (var line:String in lines){ 
        // you can do whatever you want with the String line
        result += line;
    }
```

Comment: i really appreciate your help but i am still not able to do a match in a string using regex:
 for each (var lineRaw : String in myArrayOfLines)
   { 
    
    str = lineRaw;
    str = str.match(pattern);
    trace("line:"+str);
   }

Comment: both answers were very helpful, was ble to get the string worked out. thank you very much :).